# Prometheus + Grafana - graph data shifted by 2 minutes?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I've got prometheus scraping a histogram of request latency from my API server every `1m`.

I'm then visualizing the histograms as a heatmap in Grafana. It looks like this:

[image: histogram of request latencies]

My query is:

```
sum(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket) by (le) 
- 
sum(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket offset 1m) by (le)
```

What I understand this to be doing is: take the bucket vector at the time concerned and subtract the bucket vector 1 minute prior to get the bucket vector for that minute (histograms accumulate and don't clear their buckets each scrape)

But the issue is, looking at my request logs, I see:

```
...
13:56:13 GET 304 3 ms
13:56:18 GET 304 4 ms
13:56:18 POST - -
13:56:23 GET 304 4 ms
13:56:28 GET 304 0 ms
13:56:32 GET 304 3 ms
13:56:38 GET 304 6 ms
13:56:42 GET 304 4 ms
13:56:48 GET 304 9 ms
13:56:53 GET 304 2 ms
13:56:54 POST - -
13:56:58 GET 304 2 ms

13:57:01 GET 200 2 ms
13:57:03 GET 304 6 ms
13:57:08 GET 304 4 ms
13:57:12 GET 304 3 ms
13:57:18 POST - -
13:57:21 GET 304 8 ms
13:57:21 GET 304 8 ms
13:57:23 GET 304 4 ms
...
```

As you can see, the first time there were requests of "Inf" runtime was in **13:56**, but if we look at the histogram, we don't see that until **13:58**.

Why is the data shifted by 2 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Grafana has a *Query inspector* button when you're editing a panel. You can use that to see the exact response returned by Prometheus and figure out whether the shift is introduced by Grafana or by Prometheus (or both).

One possible reason I can see this happening on the Prometheus end of things is scraping resolution. If you only scrape once a minute, then it may take up to one minute to see an increase (with an average latency of half that). If, additionally, you have recorded rules that process scraped data and you're displaying the results of said recorded rules, that also adds to the latency.

So with a 1 minute scrape interval and a 1 minute eval interval, you can see a shift of anywhere between 0 and 2 minutes (before even considering jitter due to slow targets and/or an overloaded Prometheus instance).

**Edit:** Almost forgot, you very likely also want to use `increase`/`rate` instead of subtraction, in order to nicely handle instance restarts. (Unfortunately `increase`/`rate` will skew your metrics by an amount proportional to the range divided by scrape interval and miss some samples, but you've got to pick your poison.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply! You pointed me in the right direction by thinking about scrape times, I think. Also, the advice on increase/rate is good in general. Could you check my answer and see if it makes sense?

Comment: Also, while I've got the opportunity to ask, do you think that [backfilling time-series](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/roadmap/#backfill-time-series) might be able to improve the situation when implemented? I could somehow tell the system to put the requests into the time slices that they originated in, rather than in the time-slice they finished in / were scraped at?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can account for the delay. There are two aspects at play:

- I had wrongly assumed that prometheus was preserving the timestamps of the individual events. Instead, the data in the histogram is collected at the moment the scrape hits, and the data is tagged as occuring at that moment.
- I had forgotten the details of my own instrumentation - I add the data point to the histogram metric using the prometheus client library *at the moment the request finishes* (and how could it be any other way? we want to know the latency!)

So, if the data for the request at `13:56:18` (the first long-running request) was added to the histogram at the moment the request returned (more than 30 seconds after that point), say at `13:57:15`, and then the scrape times were: [`13:56:10`, `13:57:10`, `13:58:10`], then the request which *began* at `13:56:18` would end up being part of the `13:58` scrape.